# Defining and using controller methods in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

first of all, I am total noob when it comes to OOP in JS, this is new to me so treat me like a noob.

I am building my first ember.js application and I am stuck (not the first time but I would get unstuck by myself, this is a tough one though).

I have two models:
forms
entries

Entries is of course in (one to many) relationship to forms, so each form can have as many properties.

Form properties:

```
id           : DS.attr( 'number' ),
title        : DS.attr( 'string' ),
views        : DS.attr( 'number' ),
conversion   : DS.attr( 'number' ),
entries      : DS.hasMany( 'entry' )
```

Entry properties:

```
id       : DS.attr( 'number' ),
parent_id: DS.belongsTo( 'form' )
```

Now, I have forms route that displays all forms in tabled view, and each table row has some info like form id, name etc. and that works great.

What I wanted to do is display the number of entries each form has. I figured I should do that via controller, so here is my controller now:

```
// Form controller
App.FormController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    entriescount: function() {

        var entries = this.get( 'store').find( 'entry' );
        return entries.filterBy( 'parent_id', this.get( 'id' ) ).get( 'length' );

    }.property( 'entries.@each.parent_id')

});
```

Now for some reason, when I use `{{entriescount}}` in `{{#each}}` loop, this returns nothing. It also returns nothing in single form route. Note that in both cases, {{title}} for example works.
I am wondering, am I going the right way by using controller for this, and how do I get controller to output the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that through a computed property on your form.

Something like entriesLength below and use it for display:

```
App.YourForm = App.YourForm.extend
({
    entriesLength: function () {
        return this.get('entries').get('length');
    }.property('entries')
});
```

Also this is how you would set up relationship to entries in your fixtures:

```
App.Form.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id          : 1,
        form_id     : 1,
        title       : 'Order a Pizza',
        views       : 2,
        conversion  : 0,
        entries: [3,4]
    },
```

Comment: But how does the app know which entry is bound to which form in your example?

Comment: I thought that your form is already bound to the view. Isn't it. You are displaying form already. Right? entriesLength is just like another property on that form.

Comment: I will show you my full code now, just creating jsfiddle.

Appreciating your help on this!

Comment: Ok here you go, my full application: http://jsfiddle.net/jFBBb/

I want to get a count of entries that have parent_id set to the id of the form that's currently in the loop, so that I can display that data in the table.

Any insight or suggestion at all will be very helpful.

Comment: This is link to code with correct route for single form display: http://jsfiddle.net/jFBBb/1/

Comment: I have updated my answer after looking into your code. I think that you just didn't set up relationship in fixtures correctly.

Comment: That was it, I'm such a noob :D Thanks a lot :)